# Trouble resolving project dependency issues between .NET Core and .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have .NET Core console app that references a data layer project in the same solution, and I have met with an error that I cannot resolve.

`Job` is .NET Core 2.0.

`Project` is .NET Framework 4.8.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to have your data library target .NET Standard 2.0 instead of .NET Framework 4.8.**

.NET Core and the .NET Framework are **different frameworks**.

You cannot reference a .NET Framework library from .NET Core, as this diagram from Microsoft illustrates:

[image]

To resolve this, Microsoft introduced .NET Standard for class libraries:

[image]

.NET Core 2.0 and higher, and .NET Framework 4.6.1 (but preferably higher) can both reference libraries which target .NET Standard 2.0 and lower - see [implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) on the .NET Standard documentation.

You need to re-target your library to .NET Standard 2.0. If any APIs are missing in .NET Standard which your library needs they may be available as NuGet packages instead -  you can look these up on [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/).

Note that if you're using LINQ to SQL in your data library you're out of luck as that is full .NET only and not available to .NET Standard or .NET Core projects.

*The above diagrams were sourced from [Introducing .NET Standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-standard/)*

Comment: Extremely helpful information.  My project is just too out of date for what I wanted to do.  oof.  I suppose I can create a console app in a downgraded version before I fully convert.  I didn't realize that about LINQ to SQL.. I'm in trouble there as well.  I really appreciate your response.

Comment: I have to understand best practices on that before I upgrade.  I'm always very grateful to those who spend time helping others. This took up a lot of my time!

Comment: Thought I would add a link that I found helpful.. some of my async code in the console app was causing things to throw errors that crashed the program. I was using linq to sql, but also async methods.   https://recaffeinate.co/post/how-to-await-console-application/